# Why is the "Issued to" and "Issued by" fields are numbers instead of my name? in Visual Studio when signing a program

Tags: c#, visual-studio, code-signing, publisher, strong-named-key

In Visual Studio Community, I tried signing my program by going to my program's `Properties` and then to the `Signing` tab.

Then I chose `"Choose a strong name key file:"` and created a new `strong name key file`.

I tried then signing the `ClickOnce manifests`, I clicked the `"Select from File..."` I then selected the new `strong name key file` I just created, and when I looked at the `"Certificate:"` the `"Issued to"` and the `"Issued by"` fields were weird numbers and codes instead of my name...

Orderd like that: `{code-code-code-code-code}`

I don't know if this is somehow somekind of a sensitive stuff so for any case I took a screenshot of it:

[image: The "Certificate:" where the "Issued to" and the "Issued by" were displayed.]

For any case if it is sensitive, I censored the numbers in the picture and some other stuff around that I think I don't need to show. But mainly this censored inside the circle are the weird codes that are made from numbers and letters.

This is an example of how the codes looks like:

```
{00AJLSD-CAUOG-190FE89-297G8-9570934760F}
```

I tried searching for that issue for days now on the internet and I still haven't found anything.

Is there a way to solve this? And what may was the problem that caused it? Thanks.

Comment: The "create new certificate" option will always create a self signed certificate and that may not be an option you would want. To make sure it is widely recognized you may want to use a certificate issued from a well known certificate authority (CA)